# How to create secure login controller in spring boot rest api

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I want to create Controller for Login with Spring Boot REST API. But I have no idea how to do that. I want to use either Spring Security or oauth2 for that. Please someone give an example regarding that. I want authentication from username and password which I have saved in my MYSQL database.

Answer (score 1):

there are a lot of examples on the web. 
When i started to work with Spring boot and OAuth2, i used thoses:

https://github.com/royclarkson/spring-rest-service-oauth

and https://github.com/dsyer/sparklr-boot

I hope, those examples help you. 
try it, if you any question update with questions with code samples and errors logs...

Cheers